# Using already installed Windows from Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows, virtualbox, vmware

I have both Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7 installed on my system. I want to access Windows7 while I am logged in Ubuntu. One possible way what people are suggesting is to access Windows using VirtualBox or VMWare. But the online manual explains about installing Windows inside the virtual machine and then using it. But I need to access the already installed one. Can this be done in any other way? (if not using VMWare)

Comment: When you say you want to access Windows7, do you mean that you need to have access to some files on the installation, or that you need to use applications from within Windows?

Comment: Not quite possible.  It can be done with Linux, but because windows needs to check hardware, but virtual box only simulates hardware, it's not the actual hardware; it will crash if you try to open the disk partition on which your windows is located inside VirtualBox. I've done that, it kept crashing only.

Comment: I need to use some applications.

Comment: @user2740885 which ones ? it may be possible to use them in wine or there's compatible linux alternatives

Comment: Here's also what I was talking about earlier . [Using raw disk image](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk)

Comment: I read this  long time ago and web page does not exist now, but I found it in`archive.org` https://web.archive.org/web/20160304103741/http://fds-team.de/cms/articles/2013-12/use-a-real-windows-7-partition-in-virtualbox-kvm-vmware-player-u.html

Answer (score 2):

It can done by using your physical drive as disk image. But i am not encourage to do it. it may cause some data loss or system crash. i am not responsible for any of the damage cause by using this method

1. make a virtual drive of your physical the below code

   `VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename "hdd.vmdk" -rawdisk /dev/sda`

   assuming your physical drive is `/dev/sda`
2. open virtualbox with root access

   ```
   sudo virtualbox
   ```
3. create a new virtual machine by clicking new, enter a name and in harddisk selection section select 'use an existing virtual hard disk file' browse to your home directory and select  `hdd.vmdk` . press create

if there were no errors you will see grub. select windows. now you can user windows inside ubuntu. it has limited usage.

if you are looking for running windows application install [wine](https://www.winehq.org/) (use this [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) for installing latest version)

Comment: The downside here is drivers - you need VBox drivers installed on the guest, which means you may have a broken OS for some time; as well, if you intend to use highpowered graphics in that VM, it won't work at peak performance.