# How to create virtual machine for Virtualbox from extern drive?

Tags: usb, virtualbox, windows-7, oem

I want to create a **virtual machine of a windows 7 pro system** which runs on my notebook before.

- It's connected **by USB**.
- About 40GB and the whole drive has 500GB.
- It's an **OEM version**: It doesn't run when booting by USB (only when it's intern installed) but I read about virtual machines being OEM will work?

How do I create the virtual machine?

Thank you!

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/718119/66509

Answer (score 0):

## Virtual Windows 7 Machine on USB.

- Install Ubuntu on USB. (Full not Persistent).
- Install VirtualBox in Ubuntu. (Ubuntu Software Center).
- Download the Windows 7 ISO (from Microsoft).
- Start VBox and Create a Windows 7 virtual machine.
- Don't forget to register Win 7 to keep things legal.

### Cloning Existing Windows 7 OS to Virtual Machine

- Microsoft provides Disk2VHD, ( https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/disk2vhd ) which will clone a Windows install to a VHD virtual machine.
- The Windows VHD can be used by VirtualBox as a existing virtual hard disk file when creating a virtual machine.
- Alternately VMware offers VCenter Converter that can create a virtual machine from Windows or Linux desktops: ( vmware.com/in/products/converter.html ).

I have a VBox Windows VDI on a USB2 flash drive system and AutoCAD is very slow, but it works. My VM takes up about 85GB but it has lots of Windows programs on it.

Comment: I want to transfer the system already installed and filled with my software and files to a virtual machine. Does this work?

Comment: Microsoft has a tool to clone a Windows install to virtual disk: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/create-a-virtual-machine-image-of-your-existing-hard-drive-windows/ . VMware offers VCenter Converter that creates a VMware machine from Windows or Linux desktops: https://www.vmware.com/in/products/converter.html